# containable behavior in cakephp 3.0 not working in multilevel association

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working in **cakephp2.x** about 1.5 year that was good now i had moved my self to Cakephp 3.x but i am facing a problem in fetching data with multilevel association kindly inform me that i am on the write way.
Now my problem is that !!
In cakephp 2.x : I used multilevel association in controller like this

In **CommentsController**:
Model:**Post**
Model:**Comment**

Posts **hasMany** comments (Relationship that i defined in model )
Comments **belongs** to posts

```
$this->Post->Comment->find('all');
```

This query return comment's and also their related posts too but now in cakephp 3.x

```
$this->Posts->Comments->find();
```

It just only returned comments but not related posts but when i used containable behavior like this

```
$this->Post->Comments->find('all',['contain'=>['Posts'] ] )
```

this times it shows Error **Posts is not Associated with comments** 
Now i want to know it that am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Table (models) are plural in Cake 3. It sounds like you are looking to do something like this:

```
$this->Posts->find()->contain(['Comments']);
// or
$this->Posts->find('all', ['contain' => ['Comments']]);
```

If you still get the error make sure that you have set up your associations.

```
// src/Model/Table/PostsTable.php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->hasMany('Comments');
}
```

Comment: yes man you are right but i am talking about multilevel association in cakephp 3.0 did u tried this ??
$this->Posts->Comments->find('all')->contain('Posts'); in comment controller !!!
it show's posts are not associated with comments.
But it's working fine with cakephp 2.x

Comment: Can you gist your PostsTable.php class?

Comment: You are right but  i am working in plugins that's way it doesn't allow to use contain able behavior from one to an other plugins and show error comments not associated with Posts.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this also, i think this would helpful

```
$this->Posts->find('all')->contain(['Comments']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for **cakephp 3.x**

```
$this->Posts->Comments->find()->contain(['Posts'])->all();
```

OR

```
$this->Posts->Comments->find()->contain(['Posts'])->toArray();
```

before try this make sure that your model relation hasMany and belongsTo must have correct.